# Slice letters using fractal pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can one obtain something like in the photo bellow using Tikz?[image]

Look what I've got using tikz decoration library
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.fractals}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=20pt, decoration=Cantor set]
{ \sffamily \bfseries \Huge
\begin{scope}[rotate=90]
  \clip (0,.5) rectangle +(1,-4.85);
  \draw decorate{ (0,0) -- (3,0) } node[white] at (0.5,0) { C};
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ (0,-.75) -- (3,-.75) }} node[white] at (0.5,-0.75) {A};
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-1.5) -- (3,-1.5) }}} node[white] at (0.5,-1.5) {N};
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-2.25) -- (3,-2.25) }}}} node[white] at (0.5,-2.25) {T};
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-3) -- (3,-3) }}}}} node[white] at (0.5,-3) {O};
  \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate { (0,-3.75) -- (3,-3.75) }}}}}} node[white] at (0.5,-3.75) {R};
\end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This solutions it seams to be of brute force type. I am asking you if there exists a different type of clipping to achieve this effect.

Comment: Should this only work with capital letters? If you include all letters that are smaller or have depth, the lines won't align as neat.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a recursive clipping solution.

It seems that starting with the fifth applications of the recursive calculation either the precision of TeX/PGFMath is not enough or my renderer just doesn't like it anymore.

For the row of `X`s the resolution of the PDF to PNG convertes is already too low. I've added an enormous `M` to the examples instead.

---

The solution given below clips each letter individually.

Similar to [dexteritas' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/680338) it would be possible to install a clipping over the whole area but this doesn't increase the efficiency since the parts that are clipped away in `A` are also getting clipped away in `N`. Even though this solution needs a `scope` for each letter it doesn't appear to be any slower.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains}
\tikzset{
  cantor/start/.initial=0,
  cantor/picture/.style={
    start chain=going base right, node distance=+0mm, baseline=(chain-begin.base)},
  cantor/node/.style={
    text=black, inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt, node font=\sffamily\bfseries\Huge},
  cantor/cantor/.style n args={3}{insert path={
      coordinate (@1-#1) at ({$(#2)!.33333!(#3)$}-|#3)
      \ifnum#1=1 (#2) rectangle (@1-#1)
      \else      [cantor/cantor/.expanded={\pgfinteval{#1-1}}{#2}{@1-#1}] \fi
      coordinate (@2-#1) at ({$(#2)!.66667!(#3)$}-|#2)
      \ifnum#1=1 (@2-#1) rectangle (#3)
      \else      [cantor/cantor/.expanded={\pgfinteval{#1-1}}{@2-#1}{#3}] \fi}}}
\newcommand*\cantortext[2][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[cantor/picture,#1]
  \foreach[count=\CNT from \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cantor/start}]\LTR in{#2}{
    \node[cantor/node,on chain]{\phantom{\LTR}};
    \begin{scope}
      \ifnum\CNT>0 \clip[cantor/cantor={\CNT}{chain-end.south west}
                                             {chain-end.north east}];\fi
      \node[cantor/node]at(chain-end){\LTR};
    \end{scope}}
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\Huge\bfseries\sffamily % just to have the same text in document as in TikZ
CANTOR\par
\cantortext{C, A, N, T, O, R}\par
\cantortext[cantor/start=3]{X, X, X, X, X, X}
%\cantortext[transform shape, scale=5, cantor/start=5]{M}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I came up with this solution using plain pdfTeX.
I didn't notice that you specified TikZ before I started working on this solution and by the time I had, I had already sunk some time into it.
Sorry if this doesn't help answer your question.

[image: Cantorized Cantor]

```latex
%% Useful TeX macros
\bgroup
    \lccode`\?=`\p \lccode`\!=`\t
    \lowercase{\egroup\def\rmpt#1?!{#1}}
% \idim{<dimension expression>} -> the evaluation of the expression without a dimension
\def\idim#1{\expandafter\rmpt\the\dimexpr #1\relax}

\def\gobble#1{}

% \map<\macro>{<general text>} -> applies \macro to every group in <general text>
\long\def\map#1#2{\mapA{#1}#2\nul}
\long\def\mapA#1#2{%
    \ifx\nul#2%
        \let\next=\gobble%
    \else%
        #1{#2}%
        \let\next=\mapA%
    \fi%
    \next{#1}%
}

%% Helper macros for \cantorize

\def\cantorizeA#1#2#3#4{%
    \ifnum#1>0 %
        #2 #3 \cantorwd, #4 re
        \cantorizeA{\the\numexpr #1-1\relax}%
                  {\idim{#2pt + \cantorwd,pt}}%
                  {#3}%
                  {\idim{#4pt / 3}}%
        \cantorizeA{\the\numexpr #1-1\relax}%
                  {\idim{#2pt + \cantorwd,pt}}%
                  {\idim{#3pt + #4pt * 2 / 3}}%
                  {\idim{#4pt / 3}}%
    \fi%
}

% Typeset character with width \cantorwd,
\def\cantorsetwidth#1{\hbox to\cantorwd,pt{\hss#1\hss}}
\newcount\cantorlen
% Update cantorlen and cantorwd
\def\cantorgetlen#1{%
    \advance\cantorlen by 1\relax%
    \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
    \ifdim\wd0>\cantorwd,pt\relax%
        \edef\cantorwd,{\idim{\wd0}}%
    \fi%
}
% vertical buffer around text in \cantorize
\def\cantorbuf,{.2}

\def\cantorize#1{{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
    \def\cantorwd,{0}%
    \edef\cantorht,{\idim{\ht0 + \cantorbuf,pt * 2}}%
    \cantorlen=0\relax%
    \map\cantorgetlen{#1}%
    \quitvmode\pdfsave%
        \pdfliteral{.96859 0 0 .96859 0 0 cm \cantorizeA{\cantorlen}{0}{-\cantorbuf,}{\cantorht,} W n}%
        \rlap{\map\cantorsetwidth{#1}}%
    \pdfrestore%
    \hskip\cantorlen\dimexpr\cantorwd,pt\relax%
}}

%% Showcasing \cantorize

% Bigger font for showcasing the macro
\font\bigss=cmssbx10 at 50pt

{\bigss\cantorize{CANTOR}}
```

Instead of drawing white rectangles, this clips the text so you don't need to alter anything if you plan on having a background color as well.

Answer (score 6):

#### Description

At first, each character is drawn in its own node.
As I didn't find a way to invert the result of the cantor set decoration, I started from scratch and defined a recursive function `\drawmiddleline`. It draws white lines over the text. Its four parameters are described in the code.
In the image below, I used different colors (from light red to dark red) to show how it is drawn step by step.

[image]

I saved the current level with `\cslet{dml-#2}{\level}` as the first recursive call would change the variable `\level`, that is still needed for the second recursive call.

To get the height of a letter without depth, I used:

```
\settoheight{\myheight}{\huge A}%
```

`\myspacing` defines the space between the character nodes.

Of course, you could change the font to something different, but I thought that's not the main problem here.

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\drawmiddleline}[4]{
    % #1 = char index
    % #2 = current level
    % #3 = current width
    % #4 = current yshift
    \ifnumequal{#2}{1}{
%       \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{20*#1}
%       \draw[red!\c!white, line width=#3/3] ([yshift=#4] c#1.west) -- ([yshift=#4] c\n.east);
        \draw[white, line width=#3/3] ([yshift=#4] c#1.west) -- ([yshift=#4] c\n.east);
    }{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\level}{int(#2-1)}
        \cslet{dml-#2}{\level}
        \drawmiddleline{#1}{\csuse{dml-#2}}{#3/3}{#4+#3/3}
        \drawmiddleline{#1}{\csuse{dml-#2}}{#3/3}{#4-#3/3}
    }
}

\newcommand{\cantortext}[1]{
    \foreach \char [count=\i from 0] in {#1} {
        \node[anchor=south west, inner sep=.3pt, font=\huge] (c\i) at (\i*\myspacing,0) {\char};
        \xdef\n{\i}
    }
    
    \foreach \i in {1, ..., \n} {
        \drawmiddleline{\i}{\i}{\the\myheight}{0pt}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\newlength{\myheight}%
\settoheight{\myheight}{\huge A}%
\newlength{\myspacing}%
\setlength{\myspacing}{5mm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \cantortext{C,A,N,T,O,R}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```